# CodeIgniter Select Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, variables, select

I have a simple CodeIgniter Active record query to select an ID:

```
$q = $this -> db
           -> select('id')
           -> where('email', $email)
           -> limit(1)
           -> get('users');
```

How can I assign the above ID to a variable (eg. $id) 
For example,

```
echo "ID is" . $id;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thats quite simple. For example, here is a random code of mine:

```
function news_get_by_id ( $news_id )
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT( date, '%d.%m.%Y' ) as date_human",  FALSE );
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT( date, '%H:%i') as time_human",      FALSE );


    $this->db->from('news');

    $this->db->where('news_id', $news_id );


    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row;
    }

}
```

This will return the "row" you selected as an array so you can access it like:

```
$array = news_get_by_id ( 1 );
echo $array['date_human'];
```

I also would strongly advise, **not to chain** the query like you do. Always have them separately like in my code, which is clearly a lot easier to read.

Please also note that **if you specify the table name in from(), you call the get() function without a parameter**.

If you did not understand, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to do like: `if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ){ $row = $query->row(); return $row->id; }`

Comment: I also fine separate query much easier to read, but i found this example in codeigniter documentation. I thought it might have any advantage?

Comment: Chained query looks "cool" but that's it. I have my entire code like this random example above. It's loooot easier to read;)

Comment: What is the significance of FALSE as second parameter here?

Comment: @Herr is it bad practice to use method chain? or is it related to performance?

Answer (score 3):

use **Result Rows**.
**row()** method returns a single result row.

```
$id = $this 
    -> db
    -> select('id')
    -> where('email', $email)
    -> limit(1)
    -> get('users')
    -> row();
```

then, you can simply use as you want. :)

```
echo "ID is" . $id;
```

Answer (score 2):

one short way would be

```
$id = $this -> db
       -> select('id')
       -> where('email', $email)
       -> limit(1)
       -> get('users')
       -> row()
       ->id;
echo "ID is ".$id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function news_get_by_id ( $news_id )
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT( date, '%d.%m.%Y' ) as date_human",  FALSE );
    $this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT( date, '%H:%i') as time_human",      FALSE );


    $this->db->from('news');

    $this->db->where('news_id', $news_id );


    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $row = $query->row_array();
        return $row;
    }

}   
This
```

Answer (score 0):

When use **codeIgniter** Framework then refer this active records link. how the data interact with structure and more.

The following functions allow you to build SQL SELECT statements.

***Selecting Data***

**$this->db->get();**

Runs the selection query and returns the result. Can be used by itself to retrieve all records from a table:

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

With access to each row

```
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
}
```

Where clues

```
$this->db->get_where();
```

EG:

```
 $query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id), $limit, $offset);
```

**Select field**

```
$this->db->select('title, content, date');

$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

// Produces: SELECT title, content, date FROM mytable
```

E.G

```
$this->db->select('(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) FROM payments WHERE payments.invoice_id=4') AS amount_paid', FALSE); 
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query= $this->m_general->get('users' , array('id'=> $id ));
echo $query[''];
```

is ok ;)

Comment: Good answers will explain how to look at the obstacle the problem presents, suggest a solution and explain how the two connect. 'Do it this way because it's the best way' may be an answer, but it doesn't promote *understanding*.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code

```
$q = $this -> db
       -> select('id')
       -> where('email', $email)
       -> limit(1)
       -> get('users');
```

Try this

```
$id = $q->result()[0]->id;
```

or this one, it's simpler

```
$id = $q->row()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

echo $this->db->select('title, content, date')->get_compiled_select();

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getSalary()
    {
        $this->db->select('tbl_salary.*,tbl_employee.empFirstName');
        $this->db->from('tbl_salary');
        $this->db->join('tbl_employee','tbl_employee.empID = strong texttbl_salary.salEmpID');
        $this->db->where('tbl_salary.status',0);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of the code:

```
public function getItemName()
{
    $this->db->select('Id,Name');
    $this->db->from('item');
    $this->db->where(array('Active' => 1));
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```