# $this->db->select in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, methods

I’m having problems when I try to insert a function of Select detro example DATE_FORMAT (date_end, ‘% W% M% Y’) AS dateend.

```
$ this-> db-> select (name, DATE_FORMAT (date_end, ‘% W% M% Y’) AS dateend)
```

It says the ‘% W% M% Y’ method is unknown

Answer (score 3):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408059/codeigniter-select-query) and this [forum entry](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/74206/), adding `false` to your query will do the job:

```
$this->db->select("DATE_FORMAT(your_date_field, 'Year: %Y Month: %m Day: %d') AS formated_date", FALSE );
```

Comment: I was curious to know what the `false` do.  [According to the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) : `If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks.`.