# select Name from database where emali = $emali?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need select `Name` from databese where Email = `$email`;

```
if ($result) {

        $Name = $this->db->select('Name');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('Email',$Email);

        $sess_array = array(
            'Name' => $Name 
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
        print_r($sess_array);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us your code of the db thingy you're having, it's hard to say from the code you've shown.

Comment: I need print from database

Comment: try this after where statement: `$Name = $this->db->get()->result();`

Comment: and how can I save $name in `$sess_array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
if ($result) {

    $this->db->select('Name');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('users',array('Email' => $Email));
    $result = $query->row();
    $sess_array = array(
        'Name' => $result->Name 
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
    print_r($sess_array);
}
```

also refer [CodeIgniter Select Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408059/codeigniter-select-query)

Comment: How can I Print only name value ?

Comment: just check with the value of $query `print_r($query);`

Comment: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Name] => valeri) )`
I need only print value `valeri`

Comment: So just use `$sess_array = array(
        'Name' => $query[0]->Name 
    );`

Answer (score 5):

You need to fetch Name from database then assign to your session

```
if ($result) {
        $this->db->select('Name');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('Email',$Email);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        $result=$query->row(); // fetch single data Name

        $sess_array = array(
            'Name' => $result->Name // set Name to array
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$sess_array);
    }
```