# How can I make a multiple where? A where doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

I have a problem, I need a double where but I don't why it doesn't work, it's like one of them didn't exist you know 'cause only one of them woks in the Query Builder.

This is the code:

```
$this->db->where('pro_materias.docente', $doc);
$this->db->where('pro_materias.carga', $carga);
$this->db->select("
                   pro_materias.id_materias,
                   pro_materias.carga,
                   pro_materias.materia,cat_materias.materias,
                   pro_materias.docente
                   ");
$this->db->from('pro_materias');
$this->db->join('cat_materias','pro_materias.materia = cat_materias.id_materias');
$consulta = $this->db->get();
return $consulta->result_array();
```

I tried the same, this is the query and it works perfectly:

```
SELECT 
        pro_materias.id_materias,
        pro_materias.carga,
        pro_materias.materia,cat_materias.materias,
        pro_materias.docente
FROM pro_materias
INNER JOIN cat_materias ON pro_materias.materia = cat_materias.id_materias
WHERE pro_materias.carga = 4 AND pro_materias.docente = 12345678;
```

And I tried of other two different ways, and they didn't work eather.

```
$array = array('pro_materias.docente' => $doc,'pro_materias.carga' => $carga);
$this->db->where($array);

$where = "pro_materias.docente = ".$doc." AND pro_materias.carga = ".$carga."";
$this->db->where($where);
```

I would be thankful if someone could help me.

Comment: Take a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408133/10910692 and try it.. see if its working that way

Comment: CI supports multiple `$this->db->where()`. Did you check with `echo $this->db->last_query();die;` if the generated query string is as expected?

Comment: also, have you checked if `$doc` and `$carga` have any value? does it work if you hard-code those values?

Comment: I haven't try "echo $this->db->last_query();", I'll check the response
And yes, $doc and $carga have values, and even I try with static data, but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
$this->db->where(array('pro_materias.docente' => $doc, 'pro_materias.carga'=> $carga)
```